# Client and Server program stuck after creating FTP connection

Tags: python, sockets

I have two programs, one for the client and one for the server. I am trying to establish an FTP connection between them to transfer files. The two programs connect okay and I get a confirmation from the server that it has connected to the client's ip, but I get no more output from either program.

Client:

```
# client.py

import socket                   # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))


with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
    print ('file opened')
    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

Server:

```
# server.py

import socket                   # Import socket module

port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                     # Now wait for client connection.

print ('Server listening....')

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print ('Got connection from', addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print('Server received', repr(data))

    filename='text.txt'
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
       conn.send(l)
       print('Sent ',repr(l))
       l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

    print('Done sending')
    conn.send('Thank you for connecting')
    conn.close()
```

I receive this output from the server:

```
Server listening....                                                   
 Got connection from ('192.168.56.1', 51059)
```

And this from the client:

```
file opened                                                         
  receiving data...
```

But neither program moves past this stage. I'm not sure where in the code that the problem is coming from.

Comment: This is not how the FTP protocol works. It uses two connections, one for control, and another for transfering the file data.

Comment: The client is waiting for the server to send something before it sends the file. But the server doesn't send anything until it receives something from the client. They're both waiting for the other to send something first.

Comment: you are waiting for messages in both sides after `print ('Got connection from', addr)` in server and after `print('receiving data...')` in client. You are not sending any data after the **client** connects

Comment: This is a classic case of "deadlock".

Comment: @Tengu In the [actual FTP protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959), the client establishes a connection to the server's command port, then sends a `PORT` or `PASV` command to setup an inbound or outbound transfer port (respectively), then sends a `RETR`, `STOR`, or `APPE` command to begin a transfer.  If a success reply is sent back, the client establishes the secondary connection on the agreed-upon transfer port as needed, transfers the data over that 2nd connection, and then reads a final reply on the original command connection.  The code shown is not doing ANY of that setup.